# Convert any string to fixed size string

Tags: c++, string

I use the `set_effect_block` in the following code
to convert a string to a fixed size string of 20 bytes.

```
class editoritems{

  public:

    editoritems(string= "");

    void set_effect_block(string paramnamestring)          //set effect block
    { 
      const char *effectnamevalue=paramnamestring.data();  
      int length=strlen(effectnamevalue);
      length=(length<20?length:19);
      strncpy_s(effe_block,effectnamevalue,length);
      effe_block[length]='\0';
    }

    string get_effect_block()const{return effe_block;}

  private:

    char effe_block[20];
};

editoritems::editoritems(string h)
{
  set_effect_block(h);
}
```

Is this a good way to do that ?
Is there any faster way ?

Comment: Well you certainly don't need `strlen` to get the length of a `std::string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
void set_effect_block(string paramnamestring)
{
    size_t copied = paramnamestring.copy(effe_block, 19);
    effe_block[copied] = '\0';
}
```

BTW: You might want to consider using `const std::string& paramnamestring` as parameter for `editoritems::set_effect_block()`, so that the string does not need to be copied to be passed into the function.